# Margin-top: 100% gets parent width value... strange

Tags: html, css, width

I have very strange "issue", on most browsers (ie, ff, chrome, safari).
Here is example code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <style type="text/css">
        html{
            outline: 1px #0ff solid;
            background: rgba(0,255,255,0.1);
        }
        body{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            outline: 1px #00f solid;
            background: rgba(0,0,255,0.1);
        }
        #aDiv{
            width: 300px;
            outline: 1px #f00 solid;
            background: rgba(255,0,0,0.2);
        }
        #bDiv{
            margin-top: 100%;
            outline: 1px #0f0 solid;
            background: rgba(0,255,0,0.1);
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="aDiv">
        <div id="bDiv">
            content
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When You change #aDiv width, then #bDiv margin-top will change with same value.
I dont know how it is possible, that height goes to width. Anyway maybe one of You could explain me whats going on?

Best regards ;)

D.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is actually [according to the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#margin-properties)

> <percentage> The percentage is calculated with respect to the width of
>   the generated box's containing block. Note that this is true for
>   'margin-top' and 'margin-bottom' as well. If the containing block's
>   width depends on this element, then the resulting layout is undefined
>   in CSS 2.1.

Pretty useless, right? Have you considered using `position: absolute` and `bottom: 0`? They might be more of what you're looking for.

Comment: I was working on quite different thing, however since browsers are not always working as expected, i was testing totally random attributes, as margin-top: 100% is a bit silly. And i get strange corelation between (vertical) margin-top/margin-bottom, and (horizontal) width. As you said, pretty useless ;)

Comment: what kind of moron put this in the standard.. that's.. almost unbelievable stupid, basing vertical percentages on horizontal values.

Comment: @Noishe There is [some speculation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11003911/why-are-margin-padding-percentages-in-css-always-calculated-against-width/11004839#11004839) that it's a technical limitation, due to the flow of DOM elements.

Comment: It's a weird choice, but definitely not useless especially when you want the height to match the width. Lot's of applications including most of "card" implementations ;)

Answer (score 8):

You could try *viewport relative units* ( 1vw = 1% of viewport width, 1vh = 1% of viewport height).

Tried `margin-top: 90vh;` ?

Answer (score 4):

```
#bDiv{
        margin-top: 100%; --> This need to change
        outline: 1px #0f0 solid;
        background: rgba(0,255,0,0.1);
    }
```

Its not a strange issue. It because you have set the `margin-top` to 100%, since `aDiv` is the parent of `bDiv` it take the width of `aDiv` as `margin-top`.

Comment: it was clear to me how to remove this issue, however I was curious about reason, why vertical percentage gets value from horizontal parent width. It makes no sense...

Answer (score 1):

It's all to do with your CSS on bDiv having `margin-top: 100%;`

If you remove this, everything acts normal again.

Comment: it was clear to me how to remove this issue, however I was curious about reason, why vertical percentage gets value from horizontal parent width. It makes no sense...

Comment: Please refer to Kasun's answer