# Set margin sizes with `%`... Parent or element relativity?

Tags: html, css

Let's say we have the following HTML:

```
<div id='parent'>
   <div id='child'>
   </div>
</div>
```

If we set this CSS :

```
 #parent {
     width:1000px;
     height:1000px
 }
 #child {
    width:20%;
    height:40%;
    margin-top:10%;
 }
```

The child element will have a `margin-top` that will be a `%` of the parent height or the child height? Also there is a different way that browsers render the `%` sizeing when it comes to margins ? If there is a `padding` applied to child/parent , it will influence the `margin`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to check is it [test it out yourself](http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/LDrd3/) ;)

All percentages with regards to width, height are calculated based on the parent container's width - in this case, the `#child` element will have a width of 200px and height of 400px.

Meanwhile, paddings and margins, when percentage-based, [**are calculated from the containing parent's width**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11003911/why-are-margin-padding-percentages-in-css-always-calculated-against-width): therefore `#child` will have a top margin of 100px.

Do take note that vertical margins (i.e. the top and the bottom margins) [may collapse under some circumstances](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins). In the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/LDrd3/) that I have posted, this is exactly the case.

Comment: Proof: http://jsfiddle.net/8Jcdu/ with function from [here](http://robertnyman.com/2006/04/24/get-the-rendered-style-of-an-element/)

Comment: _"It is important to note that height, when specified in percentages, refers to the percentage width of the parent element (not the height)."_ Could you pls quote that from the docs? This seems very misleading to me (percentage height calculated from parent's width? Not really...) and I couldn't find such a statement in the docs.

Comment: Directly from the W3C link: _"The percentage is calculated with respect to the height of the generated box's containing block."_

Comment: My bad - I mixed up some thing. I meant margins and paddings are calculated based on containing parent's width when specified in percentages. Had a brain fart :P