# Make padding-bottom percentage come from height rather than width

Tags: css, responsive-design, standards

Definitely having one of those WTF moments right now.

I'm trying to implement a design where the main element goes off canvas when you carry on scrolling up. Responsively, of course.

I figured it would be pretty easy to do.

```
main{
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}
```

Which, I figured would create space underneath the element equal to 100% of it's height. It didn't. Then, after some element inspecting, and some reading up on the spec, I found this horror:

> "The percentage is calculated with respect to the width of the generated box's containing block. Note that this is true for 'margin-top' and 'margin-bottom' as well."
>   -[W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#margin-properties)

This blew my mind. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11003911/why-are-margin-padding-percentages-in-css-always-calculated-against-width) asking *why* and although I'm not satisfied with the answer over there, I'm not going to duplicate the question.

What I want to know is how can I get around this bizarreness?

From one of the other comments on that question, I investigated trying to change the flow of the element in question to vertical.

> "According to dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-box/#the-margin-properties it states 'Note that in a horizontal flow, percentages on ‘margin-top’ and ‘margin-bottom’ are relative to the width of the containing block, not the height (and in vertical flow, ‘margin-left’ and ‘margin-right’ are relative to the height, not the width).' So it goes both ways." – Adam Sweeney

So I tried adding `writing-mode: vertical-rl;` but that doesn't seem to change anything. Not really sure why because I figured it might at least rotate my text or something but no change.

So yeah, I'm starting to think this might not be possible in CSS at all but that, to me, is just mental.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Then wrap a containing block of the same size around it.

Comment: How would that help when it will still just use the height of it's parent?

Comment: That's the point, isn't it?

Comment: I meant width, it got late...

Comment: `writing-mode` is CSS3, so you can try it vendor prefixed. Chrome e.g. supports `-webkit-writing-mode`.

Comment: Ah, ok thanks. That made me realise that writing-mode probably isn't going to solve that. I tried this and a few other combinations and it didn't work. `#wrapper{ 
  margin-bottom: 200%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-writing-mode: vertical-rl;
}
main{
  -webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
  width: 100%;
}`

Answer (score 0):

```
.main {
   position: relative;
   bottom: 100%;
 }
```

Just a thought.

Comment: can you show some code? I would help to figure out what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've solved my problem with a pseudo element, so I'll post how I did it here in case anyone has the exact same problem but I'll leave the broader issue of getting percentage based padding & margins to work as expected unsolved as yet.

I wanted to create a space under the `main` element that was equal to the height of the `main` element.

So, I did this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<main>Content</main>
</div>

#wrapper{
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}
main:after{
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
position:absolute;
}
```