# CSS Auto-Sizing and Positioning of stacked divs

Tags: html, css, css-position, positioning

I hope the title was clear enough to get the general idea. The problem itself is a little bit trickier. To help with the understanding see my illustration below.

Since I don't have enough reputation points to include the illustration directly, here is a link to it on flickr.com: http://www.flickr.com/photos/cumbrowski/12009919663/

Or link to image here at Stackoverflow.com: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Kswi.png

Phrasing it out in full-text.

- The **outer-most container** should always be vertically and
  horizontally centered in the available browser window. Both Width
  and Height are dynamic, but the ***height cannot exceed 90% of the
  available window height***.
- The **inside** of the container has **3 containers**.
- The **top-most** container has a **fixed height** but the width should span
  the entire outer container width.
- The **bottom-most** container should also span the entire width of the
  outer container, but it's height can vary, based on it's content.
  Preferably, If the container is empty, the height should shrink to 0
  (if possible).
- The **center-most** container controls the width and height of the
  outer-container, except, if the total height of the outer container
  would exceed the maximum of 90% of the available window height. In
  that case the center-container should show scroll bars.

**NOTE:**
If there is no pure CSS based solution possible and the help of JavaScript needed, okay, sad, but if necessary, what can I do?! jQuery would be okay in that case as well.

Comment: would something like this will help ? (it's about box-sizing) http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/kfApH vertical padding or margin in % will take parent's width as reference, not height (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11003911/why-are-margin-padding-percentages-in-css-always-calculated-against-width)

Comment: fork of initial demo http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qLakJ

Comment: While using `transform:scale` is a fun trick, it's not recommended. Everything gets scaled down, so fonts become harder to read.

Comment: nice, but not exactly what I was looking for. If the whole thing could be wrapped again and centered, that would be nice. Oh, just fyi, the whole construct is meant to be an overlay over the whole screen. First a semi-transparent full size div is put over the page content and then the construct for which I am seeking a solution here.