# css responsive box width 90% * 95% with 5% 5% 0 5% margin

Tags: css, responsive-design, percentage

What I'm trying to achieve is this:

[image]

It seems like imposible. Tried a lot of possibilities. None of them worked. This is the one I think should work.

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="content">hello</div>
</div>

html,body{
    height:100%;
}

    #wrap{
        background-color:red;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
    }

    #content{
        background-color:cyan;
        width:90%;
        height:95%;
        margin: 5% 5% 0 5%;
    }
```

Live: http://jsfiddle.net/vjb45/

Comment: It is important to note that vertical margins and paddings are computed based on the **width** of the element, contrary to common sense. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11003911/why-are-margin-padding-percentages-in-css-always-calculated-against-width. If you intend to fill up the entire viewport anyway, try using the `vh` and `vw` units instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way ( simple and small ) is to use the css prop - `box-sizing:border-box` on the container: eg http://jsfiddle.net/6EfeC/

This css will allow you to use full values of margin/padding and width combined into one unit.

```
html,body{
    height:100%;
}

#wrap{
    background-color:red;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
        /* for current ffox */
        -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    padding:2.5% 5%;
}

#content{
    background-color:cyan;
    height:100%;
}
```

---

Check - [availablity](http://caniuse.com/css3-boxsizing) and for vender prefixes. eg

`-moz-box-sizing:border-box`

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/wuqom/2/edit)

Add this

```
   position:absolute;
   left:0;
   right:0;
   bottom:0;
```

to `#content`

Also don't forget to add `margin:0;` to `body` cause the browser adds some by default.

Answer (score 0):

Write the following code into your text editor and it will work!

```
<style>
body{margin:0px;}
.contain {
background-color:black;
margin-top:5%;
margin-left:5%;
margin-right:5%;
min-height:95%;
}
</style>

<div class="contain">Content here
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by using flat property for ***content***
i have try this and it works and changing margin value and it is just apply this to ***content***

```
#content{
    background-color:cyan;
    width:90%;
    height:95%;
    margin: 5% 5% 0% 5%;
    float:right;
}
```

hope this is what you where expecting

and [here is fiddel link](http://jsfiddle.net/sandesh_mahajan/D3bsA/)