# How to prevent margins between child divs overlapping parent div when vertically responsive

Tags: html, css

I'm new to HTML and CSS so please bear with me. I am trying to create a responsive grid where a parent div has 4 child divs contained within it. Resizing the browser both vertically and horizontally when there are no margins between the child divs works successfully. However, when I begin to create margins between the child divs, resizing the browser vertically causes the bottom child div to overlap the parent div - which I do not want.

I tried using the overlap: hidden property however this causes the bottom child div to be hidden (truncated) when the browser is vertically changed - again, I do not want this behaviour.

What I want is the child divs to have equal margins and when I vertically change the browser, the child divs to be contained within the parent div, regardless of the browser vertical size.

Here is my code:

```css
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#div_container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}
#div1 {
  width: 94%;
  height: 24%;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 0% auto 1% auto;
}
#div2 {
  width: 94%;
  height: 25%;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 0% auto 1% auto;
}
#div3 {
  width: 94%;
  height: 25%;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 0% auto 1% auto;
}
#div4 {
  width: 94%;
  height: 25%;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0% auto 1% auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="div_container">
  <div id="div1"></div>
  <div id="div2"></div>
  <div id="div3"></div>
  <div id="div4"></div>
</div>
```

Hopefully my question makes sense - if not then please let me know. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Please supply jsfiddle - it will be easier for us to understand your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like ckuijjer said, the vertical values are relative to the width and not to the height.

One solution would be the usage of calc.

```css
.container div {
  height: calc(25% - 21px);
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto 28px;
  background: #f00;
}
```

[Here is an example on codepen](http://codepen.io/matuzo/pen/vELyOa). But the [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc) isn't very good.

Comment: Another solution is to align the elements equally with flexbox.

[See the pen here](http://codepen.io/matuzo/pen/pvgNgj?editors=110)

    .container {
      width: 70%;
      height: 100%;
      background: #fff;
      margin: 0 auto 40px;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: space-between;
    }

But again [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox)...

Comment: Thanks for this information matuzo - I eventually went with the calc approach. I managed to add more child divs and noticed I had to tweak the px values however it worked. Thanks again.

Comment: Great, glad I could help. Just for clarification: we subtract 21px from each element, but we only want 3 elements to have space below them. So we split the 21px of the last element evenly on the first three elements (21px + 21px/3 = 28px)

Answer (score 0):

The percentage for the `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` is based on the width instead of the height. See the discussion in [Why are margin/padding percentages in CSS always calculated against width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11003911/why-are-margin-padding-percentages-in-css-always-calculated-against-width)

It might be an option to take a look at the `vh` unit which allows you to set a size as a percentage of the viewports height

Comment: Thanks for the feedback ckuijjer - I didnt know that the margins behaved in this way so was very helpful - thanks again.