# Div - Margin-top as a percentage inside a div

Tags: html, css

This isn't working as expected. I'd basically like the **red div** to be positioned 20% from the top inside the div. This isn't working. I have provided the JS Fiddle and the code below.

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">


    <div id="inside"</div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body, html {
    margin: 0 0;
    height: 100%;
}

#container {
    background: yellow;
    height: 60%;
    width: 100%;
}

#inside {
    background: red;
    height: 50%;
    margin-top: 20%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**JSFiddle - live preview**
http://jsfiddle.net/ye947tjh/

Answer (score 0):

if you set a %-Value for a margin, it is calculated from the width of the element.

Look here for more information:
[Why are margin/padding percentages in CSS always calculated against width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11003911/why-are-margin-padding-percentages-in-css-always-calculated-against-width)

Answer (score 0):

The margin is extending beyond the container, you can use `overflow: hidden` to contain it:

```
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#container {
    background: yellow;
    height: 60%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden; //add
}

#inside {
    background: red;
    height: 50%;
    margin-top: 20%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ye947tjh/1/)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because of [Margin collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing)

so you can set the container `div` to `display:inline-block` or add some content in container `div`

with `inline-block`

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/ye947tjh/2/

with `content`

demo -http://jsfiddle.net/ye947tjh/3/

Answer (score 0):

Well you could do that or you could just use either px or cm as i prefer to make it almost desamme but because I don't know what you're trying to do I can't give you a straight answer but I don't know if it's even possible to do it, hope it helped.