# Center a text to the page based on fluid margin not working

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have been trying to set a text to center of a screen. so i placed a div with some text inside the body directly with some text and added height to it as 50% and margin-top as 50%. I thought it would hold the div's top position always at 50%. But i am wrong.

HTML:

```
<div id="test">test.. !</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
}
div {
    margin-top:50%;  
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
    height:50%;
}
```

Do you have any ideas on why it is misbehaving? Please do not suggest any new ideas. I know other ideas for centering it. But I wonder why this snippet is not working.

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/qLexoaep/2/)

Comment: It is better to use `code snippet` feature of stack overflow instead of providing link to jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is primarily a question of "50% in relation to what?"

Setting the height of the `div` to `50%` makes the height 50% of its container, in this case the `body` element.

Setting the `margin-top` to `50%` then puts a top margin to half the *width* of the `div`.

Please see this question on SO for clarification: [Why are margin/padding percentages in CSS always calculated against width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11003911/why-are-margin-padding-percentages-in-css-always-calculated-against-width)

Additionally, the top margin is applied between the parent and the *top edge* of the `div`, not the vertical centre.

All these factors play a role in the resulting `div` not being centered in its container.

Comment: I thought margin-top in percentage would be computed based on its parent height. Am i wrong?? Please explain. and provide links regarding that.

Comment: I edited the answer to add a link to another SO question that addresses this.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
 html, body {
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        margin:0;

    }
div {
    width:100%;
    height:50%;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0; 
   right: 0;
    text-align:center;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

[DEMO-JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qLexoaep/10/)