# Why does the height adjust when only width changes?

Tags: html, css

Here's my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gvopj6rx/). This is for an information kiosk style layout so I'm trying to make sure all content is visible on the screen. I'm also trying to account for a few different screen sizes so I'm using all height/width in percentage.

I want all of the .menu_item divs match the same height as #panel but the overall height on the .menu_item divs adjust as page width changes. If you take a look at the bottom border of .menu_item:last-child, and compare it with the bottom border of #panel, you'll see what I mean.

My goal with all of the .menu_item divs is to have 2% of total the #menu height between each .menu_item and then then the .menu_item divs would all have the same height and fill the rest of the content area of #menu (but not exceed it).

I'm looking to implement a solution only using html/css.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="menu">
        <div id="item1" class="menu_item"></div>
        <div id="item2" class="menu_item"></div>
        <div id="item3" class="menu_item"></div>
        <div id="item4" class="menu_item"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="weather">
        <div id="panel"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#menu, #weather {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 2%;
}
#menu {
    float: left;
    width: 65%;
    padding-right: 1%;
}
#weather {
    float: right;
    width: 35%;
    padding-left: 1%;
}
.menu_item {
    width: 100%;
    height: 23.5%;
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
    border: solid black 0.2em;
}
.menu_item:first-child {
    margin-top: 0;
}
.menu_item:last_child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
#panel {
    border: solid black 0.2em;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are margin/padding percentages in CSS always calculated against width?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11003911/why-are-margin-padding-percentages-in-css-always-calculated-against-width)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Percentages in margin/padding are percentages of width, even for top and bottom values. ([Similar question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11003911/505649), [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#margin-properties).)

If your goal is to have everything on the screen anyway, maybe you're interested in the [vh unit, 1% of viewport height, supported in many modern browsers.](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units))