# CSS Percentage Alignment Issue

Tags: html, css, alignment

**What is the problem?**

I am trying to align two boxes within divs to be on the same level as one another, whilst covering the whole page. The div widths should be 40% for the left and 60% for the right. And then the height/width of the divs inside should be `height: 100%;` and `width: 90%;`.

CSS is adding extra margin to the right div, therefore making the div's unevenly aligned from the top.

See the two examples below:

[Not working codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EgxPpz) - Unevenly aligned with correct widths.

[Aligned codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ambdPZ) - Evenly aligned with incorrect widths.

As you can see, the only change from the two codepen examples is that the width of the `TicketMainRight` div has been changed from `width: 60%;` to `width: 40%;`. This now leaves me 20% free, which I don't want. I want to keep the 60% width without the margin being increased from the top.

**Why is CSS adding more than 2.5% margin from the top when only the width is increased?**

Comment: Is flex layout an option for you?

Comment: @HerrSerker I am open to any options as long as the web page is fluid. (not static)

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not "adding more than 2.5%", it's giving margin of **2.5% of the width**.

Margin percentage is calculated against the width of the element. As for **why**, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11003911/why-are-margin-padding-percentages-in-css-always-calculated-against-width).

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. I understand that the `margin-left: 2.5%;` would be affected as I am changing the width, but I don't get why `margin-top` is being affected because I am not altering the height? @Lazar

Comment: All margins are calculated against the **width** of the element, both `left` and `top`. Check the linked question and its answers for why CSS is modeled this way.

Answer (score 2):

```
margin-left: 2.5%;
```

and

```
margin-top: 2.5%;
```

are relative to the parent's width.
So 2.5% of 40% is smaller margin than 2.5% of 60%.
You could use em.

Answer (score 1):

Percentage margin and padding values are relative to the parent elements width.
Additionally margin and padding add up to the dimensions of your element (see [box model](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp)).
So if you have a width of 100% and 2.5% margin it will be 102.5% width.
If you dont want the margin to increase while the width increases you should use a fixed margin.