# Why do I get a different result from setting translate to -50% and setting margins to 50%?

Tags: css

Assume the parent is relative, the child (style-x) is absolute. I used top 50%, left 25% to center the child.

I wish to *actually* center the child, so I set transform: translate(-50%, -50%). I am unsure if this is centered, so I double check by deleting that line and adding 'margin-top: -55px;' (half of the height), and 'margin-left: -45px;' (half of the width).

These two lines position my element in slightly different locations, yet this is different from my model of CSS. What's going on?

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#main {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 64vh;
  width: 38vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 10%;
  position: relative;
  border: 1vh solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#style-x {
  /*Why doesn't translate(-50%, -50%) give me 
      the same position as setting the margin top and
      left to half of the width and height?*/
  width: 90px;
  height: 110px;
  /*
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);*/
  margin-top: -55px;
  margin-left: -45px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 25%;
  padding: 2%;
  text-align: center;
  background: green;
}
#left-col {
  float: left;
  width: 4%;
  height: 101%;
  margin-left: 46%;
  background: black;
}
#right-col {
  float: left;
  width: 4%;
  height: 101%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-left: 0;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <section id='main'>
    <div id='style-x'>X</div>
    <div id='left-col'></div>
    <div id='right-col'></div>
    </section>
</body>
```

Here's my Codepen if you'd like a visualization.

http://codepen.io/sentedelviento/pen/ORyqzv

Comment: so you want the `style-x` center horizontally and vertically in `section`? just remove the margins and add in the `translate` you have and make `left` 50%

Comment: You didn't paste the codepen link

Comment: Thanks, fixed.

Why should I remove the margins? Why not take out the translate? I want to center it in the left half of section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem in your method. Both will try to center based on the values you provide.

The margin method fails cos you aren't using a [Box Sizing method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) like so.

```
box-sizing: border-box
```

This results in **all your elements** to be larger than the height and width specified. Without this, you are telling the browser to add any padding or border to both width & height.

And so your **larger element** shifts when using using the margin method.

You've set a `2%` padding on `style-x`, and a width of `38vw` on `#main`. When using margins to center things, you would need to account for these **varying values**.

> When you set a **percentage** padding, [its calculated based on the **width** of the containing block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11003911/why-are-margin-padding-percentages-in-css-always-calculated-against-width).

The transform method on the other hand, uses the bounding box of the containing block and has no problem centering a **larger element**.

I'd suggest you include this `box-sizing` on `main` and `style-x` if using the margin method. You could just use

```
*, after, before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

This gives better control over dimensions across all elements.