# How does padding-top: 100% work?

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

```css
    .parent {
      width: 30%;
      border: 1px dotted red;
    }

    .child {
      padding-top: 100%;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="parent">
      <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
```

And for some reason the child becomes a perfect square. This is at least weird because none of the divs have any height assigned to them. Why is this happening?

What does `padding-top: 100%` do?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d9nu3hqb/1/)

Comment: padding-bottom: 100% means "make the padding bottom as tall as the element's width", thus, it's a square, more info here: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#padding-properties

Comment: The percentage is computed on the *width* of the parent container. This is a commonly used trick to get proportionally scaled width *and* height thumbnails.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @meagar. This doesn't make much sense to me, but it seems to be just what's happening.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11003911/why-are-margin-padding-percentages-in-css-always-calculated-against-width

Comment: It makes NO sense, but it's the only solution for retaining aspect ration, regardless of width, that does not require JavaScript manipulation. AFAIK. I use `width:100%, padding-top:100%` on parent, then child img has `width:100%, height:100%, object-fit:cover, object-position:center, border-radius:50%` to make perfect circle thumbs for example.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your child div is filling parent in 100% width. Padding-top property in percent is determined by div width. So, your child is getting 100% width of parent (30%) and padding top 100% means 100% width of that element. The same applies to margin-top which is calculated by width.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: My initial answer was misleading indeed. Correct is: the child's padding percentage value is relative to its own width, which in this case equals the width of the parent. So 100% of parent's width becomes the child's top padding.

Of course, the child height itself should still be 0px in order for this to work.

Original:
The `padding-top: 100%` on the child makes it a perfect square because the child has a height of 0px and therefore the padding on the top is the only thing that takes up space.

Therefore if the height wouldn't be 0, then you would not end up with a perfect square.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Although your answer doesn't really explain why it produces a perfect square, you rightly point out the role of the 0px height of the child.