# div height in percentage does not work even with 100perc html and body

Tags: html, css

I'd like to set the `div height` using percentages that do not depend on items in it.
I got a fixed header on the top of the screen and a centered div. But set height in percentages does not work. It enlarges only if I add some items in there.

Please help.

I have this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>lol</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div id="conteiner">
    <header>
        <p>header</p>
    </header>
    <div id="main">
        <p>main info</p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this `CSS`.

```
html{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
body{
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

header{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    border: solid red 1px;
}

#main{
    display: block;
    width: 65%;
    height: 80%;
    border: solid green 1px;
    margin: 8% auto 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: You could use vh units instead of % if it is a percentage of the scren you are after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to make it's parent 100% height too.

`#conteiner` has automatic height by default because its `div` block. And default height is height of its children. If parent's height isn't set manually, children height in percents are ignoring by browser

```
#conteiner {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Jesus Christ, forgot about container, thx a lot.
One more question, please.
I got 10% height header. 
If I set margin-top for container for 10% it lays not under the header but way more lower. What's the problem? ty)

Comment: its because margins in percent calculating from blocks `WIDTH` property :(

Comment: ehm, did not get it)
Can u advice me please where can I read about this details) 
Ty

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11003911/why-are-margin-padding-percentages-in-css-always-calculated-against-width

Comment: Ty a lot))
I'm new to front-end
Java is everything for me
Ty once more c:

Comment: w8ing the timer to let me, sure m8)

Answer (score 1):

at your style file you have to write style for container div code like

```
#container{
     height:100%;
}
```