# Vertically center a div in a div in css concept

Tags: html, css

Here is my html and css code is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <style>
        body{
            background-color: deepskyblue;
        }

        .main{
            background-color: black;
            color: white;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
        }

        .inside{
            background-color: orangered;
            width: 50%;
            height: 50%;
            margin: 25%;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="inside"></div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I want it looks like:

[image]

But it actually looks like:

[image]

I am not asking how to fix it (I know I can using "position" to solve it). My question is why vertically the "inside" div box does not goes to center? From the inspect I can see that the margin(top) of "inside" does not based on "main" div box. However, horizontally the margin(left) of "inside" is based on "main" div box. I would like to know the concept of this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11003911/why-are-margin-padding-percentages-in-css-always-calculated-against-width

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/19718634/901048

Comment: <div> tags have a have a "block" display.  If you set the ".inside" class to have "display:inline-block", you will get the results you desire.

There are questions that ask what the difference between "block" and "inline-block" are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular case, the top margins are collapsing -- in effect, the 25% top margin is being transferred to the `.main` container. [You can prevent this in a few ways](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19718634/901048) -- for instance, by adding `overflow: auto` to `.main`:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: deepskyblue;
}

.main {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.inside {
  background-color: orangered;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  margin: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="inside"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering that, the reason is top (and bottom) margins will collapsing by default.

Answer (score 2):

You can use my created helper class to make your div center align vertically / horizontally / both.

```
.center-x{ position: absolute; left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);  }

.center-y{ position: absolute; top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%); }

.center-xy{ position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); }
```

Just apply one of these class in your `<div class="inside"></div>`

Hope it will solve your problem

Comment: Thank you for your answer and code. Actually, I know how to solve this problem, but what I am looking for is the concept behind this.

Answer (score 1):

Use flexbox in your `.main` rules

```
.main{
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display : flex;
  align-items : center;
  justify-content:center;
}
```

You also can remove the margin from your `.inside` element

```
.inside{
  background-color: orangered;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the code. Actually, I am not looking for how to solve this problem, what I am looking for is the concept behind this.

Comment: No problem, still want to thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `position: relative` to .main and `position: absolute` to inside. As for the concept, you have a container with relative positioning and a set with and height. Then your inner div with positioning absolute has a width of 50% + 25% margin on each side = 100%. Same goes for the height, top and bottom.

The ones that use transform, they position the element with left-top to the center of its container and then shifted by 50% of the child's height and 50% of the child's width.

```css
body{
   background-color: deepskyblue;
}
.main{
 background-color: black;
 color: white;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.inside{
  position: absolute;
 background-color: orangered;
 width: 50%;
 height: 50%;
 margin: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="inside"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, that is my solution as well. However, I am not looking for how to solve this problem, what I am looking for is the concept behind this.

Comment: Thank you for adding these concept, I really appreciate. I understand the concept after we add the "position" for both "main" and "inside" div, but still not clear without these "position" why it works for horizontally, but not for vertically? In addition, if I change all "%" to be "px" these problem still there.

Comment: Well, you need some sort of reference in order to render elements. That's what positioning provides! If that does not make sense then you need to read about positioning before you can understand margins or paddins!