# How is padding-top as a percentage related to the parent's width?

Tags: css

Here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/QZAd8/1/

Notice how all of the red divs are the same `height` and have `padding-top:100%;`, yet they A & B have different padding sizes... and it appears that the *width of the parent* changes this value (note that C changes the `height` of the parent, yet that doesn't alter the padding).

Why is padding related to width in this way?

Edit: for historical reasons, and in case jsfiddle goes away, the code I used in my example is as follows...

```css
.outer {
  background-color: green;
  height: 300px;
  width: 70px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.middle {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 50px;
  padding-top: 100%;
}

.inner {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class='outer'>
  <div class='middle'>
    A
    <div class='inner'>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class='outer' style='width:100px'>
  <div class='middle'>
    B
    <div class='inner'>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class='outer' style='height:400px'>
  <div class='middle'>
    C
    <div class='inner'>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

From [CSS fluid layout: margin-top based on percentage grows when container width increases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10629294/css-fluid-layout-margin-top-based-on-percentage-grows-when-container-width-incr) :

> In CSS, all four margin: and padding: percentages are relative to the width ...even though that may seem nonsensical. That's just the way the CSS spec is, there's nothing you can do about it.

[Straight from the horse's mouth](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/box.html#padding-properties):

```
'padding-top', 'padding-right', 'padding-bottom', 'padding-left'
Value:      <padding-width> | inherit
Initial:    0
Applies to:     all elements except table-row-group, table-header-group, table-footer-group, table-row, table-column-group and table-column
Inherited:      no
Percentages:    refer to width of containing block
Media:      visual
Computed value:     the percentage as specified or the absolute length
```

> **Percentages:     refer to width of containing block**

Comment: Nice.  How unexpected...  Thanks for finding this!

Answer (score 2):

It's true that padding percentage is relative to the width, but specifically, `padding: 100%` can also be read as `padding: *width-of-container*px`.

The **A** and **C** blocks had a width of `70px`. Applying `padding: 100%` was the same as `padding: 70px`

Answer (score 1):

Just because it's the way it is suppose to be :) http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#propdef-padding-top

Comment: it can be usefull to keep ratio of boxes

Answer (score 1):

If you came here looking for an alternative like I did, you can set padding-top as a percentage of vertical height using a CSS calculation:

```
padding-top: calc(.25 * 100vh);
```

Comment: 100vh is the height of the screen - you probably mean 100vw, which is the width?

Comment: `padding-top: 25vh` does the same thing as the `calc...` for me.

Answer (score 0):

The height of an element relies on its content, which include the padding and margin of its child elements, so that would a loop, if the child elements rely on its parent height.