# An image thats responsive but square as an <img> element

Tags: css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using Ionic 1.x and Angular 1.x, I display an avatar image thats usually square but not always, I want it to be full width, and then square, so if the screen is 720px wide, I want a 720px tall and wide image, if the image is larger than this size, it should hide the excess (ideally in a smart way).

I have only included the ionic styles, and a few of my own, so bootstrap isnt included in this project.

I would be happy applying a class with width: 100% to the image, and a height: auto, but the height should not be more than the width.

As mentioned it needs to be responsive as it will be shown on a variety of screen sizes, so the image I wont always know to set the size for... I could use some JS to manually calculate and set the sizes, but is that not a bit clunky?

I had a look for directives but could find none.

Comment: `background-size: cover` is one option.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to create a responsive square element and then use a CSS background image rather than an HTML img `src`:

- You can make a responsive element of any given [aspect ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect_ratio_(image)) with `height: 0`, `width: x%`, and `padding-bottom: y%` (or `padding-top`), where `x`/`y` is the aspect ratio. (This works because [percentage padding is relative to width](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17621322/1241736)). In your case, to make a full-width square use `height: 0; width: 100%; padding-bottom: 100%;`.
- Because you're using an `<img>`, you'll get a "missing image" outline that can't be removed with CSS. Hack around this by using a single transparent pixel as your `src` image. Base64 encoded, that's
  `src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7"` ([thanks to Chris Coyier](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/base64-encode-of-1x1px-transparent-gif/) for saving us the trouble of making our own)
- Now add your image as an inline `background-image`. Center it with [`background-position: center`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position), and use [`background-size: cover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) to make scale to fit the `<img>`. You can use the [`background` shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background) to say that in one CSS property, with `background: position/size`.

---

Here it is all together. I'm using a wrapper element just to make things fit in the snippet results window; the second image demos successfully turning a non-square image into a square.

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  background: no-repeat center/cover;
}
#wrapper-for-demo {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper-for-demo"><!-- just to fit nicely in the stacksnippets results window -->
  
  <!-- an image with a square source -->
  <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" style="background-image:url(http://placehold.it/400x400)" />
  
  <!-- an image with a non-square source -->
  <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" style="background-image:url(http://placehold.it/400x600)" />
  
</div>
```