# css vertical alignment, but not quite

Tags: html, css

How do I have a block of text be aligned such that the top of the first line is 50% down from the top of the td?

So imagine this, but the top of first row is exactly 50% down.

```
--------------
|             |       
|             | 
|             |
|     xxxx    |
|   xxxxxxxx  |
|  xxxxxxxxxx |
|             |
|             |
--------------
```

I can do it with a containing div and padding, but I want pure css option that won't break if I change the table height, line height, etc....

Edit --

here is a fiddle that display correctly but uses "hack" css that will break if I change the height and whatnot.

http://jsfiddle.net/5q9K8/

It is showing correctly, but I don't want to have that div.  I also don't understand why the padding-top needs to be 90%; would have thought 50% would do it.

Comment: Something like this? [**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/5q9K8/5/)

Comment: close, but in that case the td with the single line should be vertical align middle, and the first line of the other td should line up with it.

Answer (score 1):

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5q9K8/10/

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            xxxx<br/>
            xxxxxx<br/>
            xxxxxxx
        </td>
        <td>
            xxxx
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Css:

```
td {
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;

    vertical-align:top;    
}
td:before{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 50%;
}
```

Logic: Using before element to occupy 50% of the TD space so that text starts exactly from the middle & adding vertical align top to keep the text align top from center.

Comment: @fiction really? so what if I change the `width` to `200px` (which is equal to the `height`) http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/5q9K8/6/

Comment: Great i could help, border-box means the padding will be counted as a part of height, which means the total sum of height will be 200px in this case even after applying 50% padding.

Comment: the td with the single line should appear as if vertical align is middle and the td with multiple lines should have its first line line up with the single line.  In your example the text is too low

Comment: @KingKing I guess the % padding is acting werid ... if you change the 50% to 100px it will work fine even with Width 200px.

http://jsfiddle.net/5q9K8/8/

Comment: Yeah i don't get why 50% padding is resulting in it being aligned to the bottom when the width is 200px

Comment: @fiction I just noted that 50% is not the 50% of TD but something else... after increasing the height of TD the % remained the same... weird...

Comment: it seems css padding percentages are calculated from the width

Comment: nice, works if you change width/height and font size now

Comment: Hey i just ran in to the width % being used for height % issue and this is what i found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10629294/css-fluid-layout-margin-top-based-on-percentage-grows-when-container-width-incr do check it out :)

Answer (score -1):

Change the margin of the block.
Use `margin-top:50%;`
Or try a `vertica-align:center;`
That would align it to the middle, i suppose that's why you want those 50%

Comment: @hvgotcodes it works in your fiddle if you remove `height:100%` from `.x`

Comment: close, but the top rows are not aligned if I do that.

Comment: could you edit some fiddle? I doubt that this solution can't work for different pairs of **height** and **width** of the `td` element. BTW, what kind of `vertical-align:center`?

Comment: it breaks if you change the font size.  using margin-top: 50% puts the top of the div at the middle of the container, and since the text is in the div, its *below* the middle point of the container

Comment: See [This link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249359/text-vertical-align-in-a-div)