# How can I prevent the browser's width from affecting the vertical position of text?

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML and CSS

```
<body>
<p>Foo Foo Foo</p>
</body>

p {
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-top: 20%;
}
```

If you were to open this code in a browser, decreasing the browser's width would make the text move upwards. What is the easiest way to avoid this?

Comment: This is related to your question and might answer it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266363/margin-top-percentage-does-not-change-when-window-height-decreases

Comment: Thank you, @RichardHaber – the link in the accepted answer was very resourceful. (http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/box.html#margin-properties)

Comment: Have you seen the viewport units (vw, vh, vmin)?  http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

Comment: @cimmanon I had not but thank you for commenting – that is a really interesting post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you can do nothing about it. Even if you do something to make it work(like making container an inline element) it would be a hack.

> The percentage is calculated with respect to the width of the generated box's containing block. This is true for 'margin-top' and 'margin-bottom' as well.

Read more at [W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/box.html#margin-properties)

Answer (score 1):

The `margin-top` value is computed based on the width of the viewport (screen window).

You need to use another relative unit like `em` or an absolute unit like `px`.

It depends in part on the effect you are trying to create.

See Reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#margin-properties