# CSS margin-top is incorrect value

Tags: html, css

I have very simple markup and style rules that should put my `div` in the middle of the page, but it does not (actually, the top of the div would be at the middle, not 100% truly centered vertically) when the viewport is of a small enough height.

HTML:

```
<div>adf</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    background-color:red;
    margin-top:50%;
}
```

You can look at my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uvxt7j77/) to see this. It will require you shrink the rendered window (bottom right) a bit, as it is correct initially.

Comment: `margin-top` uses the width of the element when using percents. See the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266363/margin-top-percentage-does-not-change-when-window-height-decreases

Comment: See [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#margin-properties): The percentage is calculated with respect to the **width** of the generated box's containing block. Note that this is true for 'margin-top' and 'margin-bottom' as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `50%` try `50vh`

`50%` doesn't do what you think it would - it actually uses the `width` of the parent container, not the `height` to calculate.

Comment: Keep in mind that not all browsers support the vh unit. http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

Comment: I remember reading about this... It's very annoying.

Comment: Good point fanfavorite - this won't work in IE8 at all.

Comment: @fanfavorite Thanks. The support is good enough for me; only a personal project.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing percentages with `vh`

```css
div {
    background-color:red;
    margin-top:50vh;
}
```

```html
<div>adf</div>
```

[Here](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/) are more cool stuff about viewport sized measures

Comment: Your answer is essentially a repeat of willoller's.

Comment: well, I didn't see an answer was posted when I was copying code to snippet. So it seems you downvote me. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah not sure that deserves a downvote - those hang around, you know?

Comment: I know, but you say I have to delete my own answer, which is right and helpful, because someone posted answer half a minute before me?!

Comment: It's nothing personal. It just makes it hard for future readers to find the complete answer in a nice way. willoller's answer should just be edited and improved with your info. It happens all the time.

Comment: I delete my answers when I get scooped, but I don't downvote answers for being essentially too late. According to mods, though, downvotes are the right action since they encourage the user to delete and get some rep back (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255571/what-to-do-with-late-answers-which-retread-the-same-ground-as-previous-answers/255602#255602 and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/263046/should-i-delete-my-own-downvoted-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution: 
http://jsfiddle.net/nb6pq14v/

```css
html, body{height:100%; margin:0;padding:0}
 
.container-fluid{
  height:100%;
  display:table;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}
 
.row-fluid {height: 100%; display:table-cell; vertical-align: middle;}
 
 

.centering {
  float:none;
  margin:0 auto;
    background: #abc;
    height: 25px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="centering text-center">
           
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is very verbose compared to other answers, including an option to simply change the units I was using. Other viewers should be directed there.

Comment: Okay, anyway the code is compatible with all the browsers. Just wanted to give it a try. All the best.